# How to read files from Azure storage explorer in Python as a function?

Tags: python, azure

I want to convert the following code as a function so that it can replicated to read multiple files:

```py
data = container.download_blob(data)
try:
    print ("Reading the Grower data from blob")
    df  =  pd.read_csv(BytesIO(data.readall()))
    print ("Data read successfully")    
except Exception as e:
    print ("Data load failed due to :" + str(e))
```

I created the following function:

```py
def download_func(filename,dataframe):
    filename = container.download_blob(filename)
    try:
        print ("Reading the Data from blob")
        dataframe  =  pd.read_csv(BytesIO(filename.readall()))
        print (str(filename)+" data read successfully")    
    except Exception as e:
        print (str(filename)+" data load failed due to :" + str(e))
download_func(data,df)
```

but there is a name error coming for df

How can I proceed from here? Would be grateful for any help!

Comment: Could you please help me with the error details that you received for df

Comment: “*but there is a name error coming for df*” Ok, you’re passing `df` as a parameter to `download_func()`, but where do you define it before using it…?

Answer (score -1):

- *You can read the files from azure storage explorer in python as a function check the [`Azure Storage SDK for Python`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage)*

```py
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService

block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='myaccount', account_key='mykey')

block_blob_service.get_blob_to_path('mycontainer', 'myblockblob', 'out-sunset.png')
```

- *for more information you can go through the SDK [documentation](https://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/)*